# How to select an option from a dropdown menu via where it is in the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way in python with selenium that instead of selecting an option using a value or name from a drop down menu, that I can select an option via count? Like select option 1 and another example select option 2. This is because it's a possibility that a value or text of a drop down menu option can change so to ensure an option is selected, I just want to say select the first option (regardless what it is) and for another example select the fifth option etc.

Below is the code I have using value to select an option which will be a problem if the value changes in the future:

```
pax_one_bags = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl02_baggageOutDropDown"))
pax_one_bags.select_by_value("2")

pax_two_bags = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl03_baggageOutDropDown"))
pax_two_bags.select_by_value("5")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is [`select_by_index()` method](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_index):

```
pax_one_bags = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl02_baggageOutDropDown"))
pax_one_bags.select_by_index(1)
```

Or, you can also get the item from the `options` list by index and click:

```
pax_one_bags = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl02_baggageOutDropDown")
pax_one_bags_select = Select(pax_one_bags)

pax_one_bags.click()
pax_one_bags_select.options[1].click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first count the numbers in the drop downlist and then using loop you can select the index at that particular location

pax_one_bags =Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_MainContent_passengerList_PassengerGridView_ctl02_baggageOutDropDown"))

int l = pax_one_bags.count();

for( int i =0 i <  l-1; i++)

{

System.out.println("First index is:"+ i[0]);

}